# code works without error on localhost, but giving SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data on 000webhost

Tags: php, json, hosting, web-hosting

i am working on an python GUI application, and this part is back end of it. i am really unknown to JSON. and familiar with little bit of PHP. if possible, please give me the exact line of code where should i change it.

code giving SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data
my local php version is v 8.1.12 is this a problem?
?

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    // Include database connector
    include 'database_connector.php';
    
    // test connection
    if (isset($_POST['test_connection'])) {
        $data['connection_response'] = "OK";
    }

    // check app key and id
    if (isset($_POST['checkapp'])) {
        $data['valid_app'] = False;
        if (!isset($_POST['app_key']) or empty($_POST['app_key'])) {
            $data['response_message'] = "Invalid app key";
        }elseif (!isset($_POST['app_id']) or empty($_POST['app_id'])) {
            $data['response_message'] = "Invalid app id";
        }else{
            if (checkAppKey($_POST['app_id'], $_POST['app_key'])) {
                if (checkAppKeyExpiration($_POST['app_key'])) {
                    $data['response_message'] = "App key expired! Please login";
                }else{
                    $data['response_message'] = "Valid app key and id";
                    $data['valid_app'] = True;
                    $userDetails = getAppUser($_POST['app_id']);
                    if(!empty($userDetails) && isset($userDetails['user_name'])){
                        $data['username'] = $userDetails['user_name'];
                    }else{
                        $data['username'] = "";
                    }

                    $appDetails = getAppDetails($_POST['app_id']);
                    if(!empty($appDetails) && isset($appDetails['key_expiration_date'])){
                        $data['expiry_date'] = $appDetails['key_expiration_date'];
                    }else{
                        $data['expiry_date'] = "unknown";
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $data['response_message'] = "Invalid app id or key";
            }
        }

        $data['app_id'] = $_POST['app_id'];
        $data['app_key'] = $_POST['app_key'];
    }

    
    // view if app key already exists
    function view_app_key($link)
    {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `applications` WHERE `application_key`='".$link."'";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
        $query->execute(); 
        $result = $query;
        if ($row = $result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){
            return "true";
        }else{
            return "false";
        }

    }

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

the full code is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5qLAZW5qachxWuc4ibtDMCH5KochjuS/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax call try this Simply change,

```
var respons = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

to

```
var respons = response;
```

**Explanation:**
If the configuration of your AJAX call is having dataType: json you'll get a JavaScript object so it's no longer necessary to use JSON.parse().

Comment: can you please tell me in my code where i should change this? because my code has nothing like parseJSON(response); i am new to json things.

Comment: at the end of code you provided above there is one line **echo json_encode($data);** ,
that indicates the response to the ajax call. From where you call the **view_app_key** method there you can use response directly, without using "parseJSON".

Comment: i am still unable to get it. should i change echo json_encode($data); to echo $data;?  here is my full code: https://codeshare.io/X81Ex8

Comment: can you please share the code from where you call *8view_app_key()**  method?

Comment: the full web app with database:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5qLAZW5qachxWuc4ibtDMCH5KochjuS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i am working on an python GUI application, and this part is back end of it. i am really unknown to JSON. and familiar with little bit of PHP. 
if possible, please give me the exact line of code where should i change it.

Comment: I go through your code and found that you don't need **echo json_encode($data);** this code. because you already return the result.

Comment: i removed "echo json_encode($data);" from index.php, still getting same error:
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: I run your code in my local system and it runs fine. no error. https://pasteboard.co/VRrvHnm1A8GE.png refer this link.

Comment: you use $_POST please add that file also.

Comment: yes, that's the exact problem, code also working on my xampp yesterday, and today i turned on my pc, same code, without any change, stopped working.

Comment: I execute the index.php file. the **null** response is from echo json_encode($data). none of the other method you defined is called from index.php. I need the post data for that to check your condition like $_POST['login'].

Comment: https://freeimage.host/i/HTXxFAx
https://freeimage.host/i/HTXxJcu

post data is null. its giving error on index.php 
also one strange thing, in json, its giving errro, and in Raw Data, its null. you can see the images

Comment: code is working yesterday on my xampp also, but given error after uploading it to 000webhost. is this a php version issue?